# React Native: Unhandled promise rejection [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'checkFav[0].name')]

Tags: android, react-native, visual-studio-code

I keep getting every time I enter this page/first-time app load data unless I try to ctrl+s file while android on debugging, the app works fine.
How do I fix this? Thx:)

error on filter multidimensional array then I call the already filter array name

```
const userProfile = async () => {
    let recipeId = props.route.params?.id ?? null;
    // let recipeId = 3;
    setGiveId(recipeId)
    const list = await authAction.RecipeShow(recipeId);
    setrefresh(list)
    let dataShow = list.data;
    setRecipeName(dataShow.name)
    setImage(dataShow.imageUrl)
    setDescription(dataShow.description)
    let dataFav = await authAction.FavRecipe()
    setData(dataFav.data)
    setIsLoading(false)
    let checkFav = ''
    let check = []
    if (data) {
        checkFav = data.filter((item) => item.name === recipeName);
        // try {
        check[0] = checkFav[0].name;
        // } catch (err) {
        // userProfile()
        // console.warn(err)
        // }
    } else if (data === 'empty') {
    } else {
        setData('empty')
    }
    console.log(check);
    let listFav = [];
    if (check === recipeName) {
        listFav[0] = {
            name: check,
            favorite: true
        }
    } else if (check != recipeName) {
        listFav[0] = {
            name: check,
            favorite: false
        }
    }
    setIsFavorite(listFav[0].favorite)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

checkFav does not seem to get resolved or checkFav is not what you expect it to be at least

```
checkFav = data.filter((item) => item.name === recipeName);
```

it looks like this is not resolving to anything at least not at the point where you want it to. To change it you could use async wait or .then() chain.
Something like:

```
checkFav = data.filter((item) => item.name === recipeName)
.then(resp =>{ DO SOMETHING WHERE CHECKFAV IS NEEDED}).catch [...]
```

Comment: Hmm, I did try this method and log the response first but I still got the same error

Comment: did you add code for catching the error?

Comment: Yes I did, put catch(err => console.warn(err)), also I did try another method using try catch finally, it did work and ignore the error, but the only problem now is that everytime user enter page favorite still set to false, the system should be set favorite to true since the data has been post inside the favorite list

Comment: this is the error I got using .then 
TypeError: data.filter(function (item) {
                return item.id === recipeId;
              }).then is not a function. (In 'data.filter(function (item) {
                return item.id === recipeId;
              }).then(function (resp) {
                console.log(resp);
              })', 'data.filter(function (item) {
                return item.id === recipeId;
              }).then' is undefined

Comment: okay can you check typeof checkFav? Is it available after line checkFav = data.filter((item) => item.name === recipeName);? Maybe it is not the object that you try to access? Another thing you can try is to wrap the data.filter with a New promise that resolves in the data.filter, it should be possible to use .then afterwards. - oh I see you could use try and catch, which means you got that working. Then please check first question, whether it is really the object that you want to access.

Comment: yup, I just finish retrace it, it seems that the problem comes from using usestate instead of just directly use let or const then filter

Comment: so when user open the page for first time, array inside usestate is empty